# Most efficient way to create form with Jquery based on server data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, performance

I have a database webmethod that I call via Jquery ajax. This returns an array of data objects from the server. For each data object I want to populate a form with maybe a couple dozen fields.

What is the most efficient way to generate and populate these forms.

Right now, I create a string of the html in my javascript code for each record and then add it to the page. Then I add some events to the new elements.

This works OK in firefox, about 700 ms total for an array of 6 elements, and 4500 ms for an array of 30 elements. However, this is an internal app for my company, and the clients can only use IE8 on their machines. In IE8, this takes 2-10 SECONDS! for and array of length 6 and 47 seconds the one time it was actually able to complete for an array of length 30. Not sure what the @#$% IE8 is doing, but anyways... I need something more efficient it seems...

Thanks!

MORE INFO:

Edit: first thing I do is:

```
$("#approvalContainer").empty();
```

Web method signature:

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<User> ContractorApprovals()
```

So I call the method and then do this with the data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            displayUserResult("#approvalContainer", data[i], false);
        }
        formEvents("#approvalContainer");
        $("#approvalContainer").show("slow");
```

displayUserResult looks like this:

```
var div = "<div style=\"width:695px\" class=..........."
fillForm(div,data)
$("#approvalContainer").append(div)
```

formEvents does things like add click events, create styles buttons and add watermarks.

fillForm does stuff like this:

```
$(userForm).find(".form-web-userName").text(userObject._web._userName);
```

where userForm is the div created in the displayUserResult function, and userObject is one of the objects in the array returned by the ajax call.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: sure. um, i'll try to cut out something short and meaningful...

Comment: This really depends on how you use the ajax data to determine how to populate the form. What's the logic there, and what's the format of your JSON?

Comment: @Nalum and Box - does the posted additional info help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing too much DOM manipulation. Every `.append` and `.find` and `.text` inside your loop makes it slower.

The most efficient way is to build an entire HTML string and append that **once**. I'm not going to bother with the `displayUserResult` function, and just modify your function that handles the data:

```
var div = "<div style=\"width:695px\" class=...........",
    html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     // Keep adding on to the same html string
     html += div + data[i]._web._userName + "</div>";
}
// After the loop, replace the entire HTML contents of the container in one go:
$("#approvalContainer").html(html);
```

However, while this is fast, note that this is only appropriate if `_userName` doesn't contain special characters, or is already HTML escaped.

Comment: so rather than using the elements class to insert the data into the form just do it as the form is being created... OK. that sounds reasonable.

Comment: I have heard a couple of people mention creating the forms on the server and sending to the browser. Whats that all about? and is that something I might want to do here? P.S. I have a couple of dozen fields to populate along with the userName.

Comment: And why is firefox able to do this so much faster than IE8? Is it really that many more times efficient?

Comment: how should i do this if i need to put values into input fields?

Comment: Also I have to attach a data to **each** of the divs. `$(div).data(...)` How should I do this?

Comment: @kralco626, creating forms on the server is certainly an option. In your case it would involve sending the full HTML in the AJAX response, rather than JSON. Server-side templates are more efficient than DOM manipulation while safer than constructing HTML strings manually. The downside is that it is more difficult to do processing of the data compared to if it had been sent via JSON.

Comment: @kralco626 to put values in input fields, you HTML string needs to contain: `"<input value='someValueHere'>"`. As for attaching data, I would do so *after* adding the elements to the form. jQuery keeps its own cache for attached data, therefore it doesn't affect the DOM.

Comment: @Box - thanks for the information. I'm working on implementing the solution now.